# exception in xpath when the next element is a text

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping this page
http://www.modeluxproperties.com/?act=list_web&m=search&purpose=sale&project=&type=32&beds=&lop=&Submit.x=37&Submit.y=20

I want to get the value of the `parking` attribute:

the html is this:

```
<span class="smallredtext" style="font-size:12px;">
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> Status: for <b>Sale</b>
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> Ref No: <b>AFS503</b>                                     
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> BUA: <b>1700 Sq.Ft.</b> 
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> Bedroom: <b>2</b>
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> Bathroom: <b>3</b>
    <img src="images/listwebpoint.png" width="6" height="6"> Parking: <b>1</b>
</span>
```

this is my xpath:

```
.//span[@class='smallredtext'][normalize-space(text())=Parking:]/following-sibling::b[1]/text()
```

I got this error:

```
raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % query)
ValueError: Invalid Xpath: //span[@class='smallredtext'][normalize-space(text())=Parking:]/following-sibling::b[1]/text()
```

#### I am using scrapy with python 0.27

Comment: Please replace your screenshot with a copy/paste of the text from the `cmd` window :)

Comment: @JonClements first of all, I already copied the most important part, which is the xpaht. secondly, i think it is readable with image. third, i want to clarify that i am using scrapy because in the past i said that in the question, but people keep suggest answers out of scrapy

Comment: SO has searchable questions and answers that may be of use to someone else in the future. By including your exception message as an image it means the post is missing indexable information so it's less likely to be of us if someone gets a similar error message. If it's text - post it as *text*... (You didn't post your XPath as a screenshot of your editor after all :p)

Comment: @JonClements you are right, I will change it, but you should have told me that information from the first ;)

Comment: my bad - I should have explained better first time around... But thank you very much for the edit - good luck with the project.

Comment: @JonClements you would be a great moderator I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the `b` tag and check for `precending-sibling`:

```
.//span[@class='smallredtext']/b[preceding-sibling::text()=' Parking: ']/text()
```

UPD (using `normalize-space()`):

```
.//span[@class='smallredtext']/b[preceding-sibling::text()[normalize-space() = 'Parking:']]/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got this `<br>1</br>` I want to get just `1` could you improve it please?

Comment: It works, but i have one question, i would like to use a normalise-space function. i tried this `>>> sel.xpath(".//span[@class='smallredtext/b[normalizespace(precedingsibling::text())='Parking:']/text()")` but i got empty results, why please?